# React fetch / doPost is not returning data

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, frontend, react-fullstack

I am trying to submit a form in react, upon submission, input will be passed to backend, and some result will be passed back. However, my code is not passing anything back to the client.
The doPost() function is invoked, but nothing has been written back.

This is my form in react

```
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      address: "",
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(evt, field) {
    this.setState({ [field]: evt.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    fetch("/sandbox", {
      method: "post",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
    }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <p>Enter your name</p>
      <input
        name = 'name'
        type='text'
        onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event, "name")}
       <p>Enter your address</p>
      <input
        name = 'address'
        type='text'
        onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event, "address")}
      />
      <input
        type='submit'
      />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my backend java code

```
@WebServlet({ "/sandbox" }) 
public class test extends HttpServlet {
    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        SandBoxInputPoJo sandBoxInputPoJo = new SandBoxInputPoJo(req.getParameter("name"),req.getParameter("address"));

        try {
            String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(sandBoxInputPoJo);
            resp.getWriter().write(json);
            resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
            System.out.println("Unable to return values for the provider view" + e);
        }

    }
```

This is my pojo class

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
class SandBoxInputPoJo {
    @NonNull private String name;
    @NonNull private String address;
}
```